# How to run a query and return the results in csv format

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert a query using the BigQuery command-line tool, to instead be done using Go but I am not finding how I should configure the query correctly. The command I have sets the format to CSV, the maximum number of rows to output, maximum bytes billed, and the project id; then runs a standard SQL query and writes the output to a CSV file while removing the headers and blank lines at the top.

Below is the command I have working correctly using the command-line tool:

```
bq query --format csv \
  --max_rows <max_row_int> --maximum_bytes_billed <max_bytes_billed_int> \
  --project_id <project_id> "#standardSQL
    <standard_sql_statment>
  " \
  | tail -n +3 >results.csv
```

I can see from the docs to run a query in Go I need to create the client/connection and then I should be able to run the query as below:

```
ctx := context.Background()

client, error := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "<project_id_string>")
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

q := client.Query(<standard_sql_query>)
```

How can I set the configuration flags I have above in my command-line tool code in my Go code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QueryConfig from the package `bigquery` [1] [2], which holds the configuration for a query job. There, for example, you will find `MaxBytesBilled` which is an analogy of the `--maximum_bytes_billed` flag.

Saving the output result is not a specific feature of the BigQuery package. You can use the `encoding/csv` package [3] for this purpose.

[1] - https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery

[2] - https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/master/bigquery/query.go#L26

[3] - https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/

Comment: Thanks, I see the MaxBytesBilled flag in the docs. Is it also possible to set the other options, like the output format to CSV? I don't see that in the docs.

Comment: I have replied about this by editing the answer above, please check.

Answer (score 0):

here is the reference implementation for libraries https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries

then you can execute your script:

GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT=project-id ./script.go